# Is there a way to obtain the default context in Z3?

Tags: z3, z3py

I am using the z3py API (4.3.0). I can easily translate an expression `expr` from the default context to a new context `target_ctx`, using `expr.translate(target_ctx)`. But how can I translate from a given context `ctx` into the default Z3 context? Is there a way to obtain the default `Context` from the Python API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be accessed through `main_ctx()`.

Here's the Python API describing `main_ctx`: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/z3.html#-main_ctx

Another way to do this is with `object.ctx` from any object created without a reference to a specific context (which uses the global context `main_ctx()` by default).

Here's the Python API describing `Context` which discusses some of this: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/z3.html#Context

Here's an example showing these approaches (z3py link: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/1sN ):

```
x, y = Reals('x y')

print x.ctx == y.ctx # True
ctx_default = x.ctx
print x.ctx == main_ctx() # True

ctx1 = Context()
x1, y1 = Reals('x1 y1', ctx1)
print ctx_default == x1.ctx # False
```