# Z3Py How to get values after solve() function

Tags: python, z3, z3py

Could someone explain how to access the result values of the equation variables, when using the solve() function of the https://pypi.org/project/z3-solver/.

```
x, y = BitVecs('x y', 32)
solve(x + y == 2, x > 0, y > 0)
```

I have tried following to no avail

```
m = solve(x + y == 2, x > 0, y > 0)
print(m.x)
```

Mind, in this scenario we do not want to use the *Solver*

```
s = Solver()
s.add(And(x + y == 2, x > 0, y > 0))
s.check()
m = s.model()
print(m[x], m[y])
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no direct way. Function `solve()` prints the found solution but does not return the model.

The definition of `solve()` in file [z3.py](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/python/z3/z3.py):

```
def solve(*args, **keywords):
    """Solve the constraints `*args`.

    This is a simple function for creating demonstrations. It creates a solver,
    configure it using the options in `keywords`, adds the constraints
    in `args`, and invokes check.

    >>> a = Int('a')
    >>> solve(a > 0, a < 2)
    [a = 1]
    """
    s = Solver()
    s.set(**keywords)
    s.add(*args)
    if keywords.get('show', False):
        print(s)
    r = s.check()
    if r == unsat:
        print("no solution")
    elif r == unknown:
        print("failed to solve")
        try:
            print(s.model())
        except Z3Exception:
            return
    else:
        print(s.model())
```

So, `solve()` is just a wrapper function. It creates a `Solver()` and does not expose the resulting model to access the variables.

Comment: seems for demonstration matters purely. I'm trying to research from here a bit further

Comment: It is possible to access the default context via `main_ctx` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493305/is-there-a-way-to-obtain-the-default-context-in-z3). I haven't found a way to get the default model via this context, though.

Comment: As Alex mentioned, use `solve` only if you do *not* need access to the model any further. Otherwise, declare the solver yourself. This is the official way to access the model variables; any other "trick" is unlikely to be robust enough with respect to internal changes to z3 itself.